# Oracle password generator for EBS database users

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have task where I need to change passwords for current EBS 189 schemas (Oracle 12.1). I have created query how to manage this in one go:

```
select 'FNDCPASS APPS/atesta 0 Y SYSTEM/test ORACLE '||oracle_username||' '||password||'' oracle_username from FND_ORACLE_USERID
where READ_ONLY_FLAG='A'
```

So my question is how to replace password word in my query with random generated password?
Password needs to have at least 15 characters, 1 special character, one number and one Upper letter.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can create a function to return such random passwords and use it in your queries:

```sql
-- function:
with 
function get_rand_pass(n in number) return varchar2 as
  res varchar2(15);
begin
   loop
     res:=DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('p',15);
     exit when
          regexp_like(res,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]') -- special char
      and regexp_like(res,'\d') -- at least one number
      and regexp_like(res,'[A-Z]') -- at least one UPPER letter
      ;
   end loop;
   return res;
end;
-- end of function
-- test query:
select 
   get_rand_pass(dbms_random.value()) pass
from dual;
```

Full example:

```sql
with 
function get_rand_pass(n in number) return varchar2 as
  res varchar2(15);
begin
   loop
     res:=DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('p',15);
     exit when
          regexp_like(res,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]') -- special char
      and regexp_like(res,'\d') -- at least one number
      and regexp_like(res,'[A-Z]') -- at least one UPPER letter
      ;
   end loop;
   return res;
end;
select 
   get_rand_pass(dbms_random.value()) pass
from dual
connect by level<=10
/

PASS
---------------
C7Bncs'bH9+Hx&p
kHG<&4Aw36VS3W
np xvyvM]3In #{
%A1&+}XVNyBvL'%
+,Bp hII\q,&7>V
h@l` kE(b4=-C</
(c{7"`~UvN44#e/
<_s+4G!nlujcytJ
{[a2{*sXW;;$#<.
7)^>Qj4!1MTm?};

10 rows selected.
```

2. or use the following subquery in your queries:

```sql
  (
  select pass
  from
    (select DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('p',15) pass from dual connect by level<=1e5)
  where
    rownum=1 -- first pass
    and regexp_like(pass,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]') -- special char
    and regexp_like(pass,'\d') -- at least one number
    and regexp_like(pass,'[A-Z]') -- at least one UPPER letter
  ) pass
```

But it may be cached ([scalar subquery caching](http://orasql.org/2013/03/13/deterministic-function-vs-scalar-subquery-caching-part-3/)) and if you use cross join with such generator, it may be executed just once in `hash join`, so it needs a workaround, for example:

```sql
select--+ use_nl(pass_gen)
  *
from FND_ORACLE_USERID,
  lateral(
    select--+ no_merge no_unnest
       pass
    from
      (select DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('p',15) pass from dual connect by level<=1e5)
    where
      rownum=1 -- first pass
      and regexp_like(pass,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]') -- special char
      and regexp_like(pass,'\d') -- at least one number
      and regexp_like(pass,'[A-Z]') -- at least one UPPER letter
  ) pass_gen;
```

As you can see here I forced `nested loops` and disable merge and unnest transformations.